# Android - How to make google-search style popup window under edittext?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm trying to make Google-search style popup window under EditText.
For example - I'm typing search request in EditText, and under will be shown small popup window with results from DB. So, this popup window must be refreshed every time I typed new letters in my query, as Google search is working.
Is it right to use **PopUpWindow** in my case? I'm looking for similar solution but with no success (((

Comment: use AutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [FloatingSearchView](https://github.com/renaudcerrato/FloatingSearchView)

[image]

Add a FloatingSearchView to your view hierarchy

```
<com.mypopsy.widget.FloatingSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        app:logo="@drawable/logo"
        app:fsv_menu="@menu/search"/>
```

in Activity

```
mSuggestionsAdapter = new MySuggestionsAdapter(); // use a RecyclerView.Adapter
mSearchView.setAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);
...
mSearchView.setOnIconClickListener(...);
mSearchView.setOnSearchListener(...);  
mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(...);
mSearchView.setOnSearchFocusChangedListener(...);
```